# In C, is specifying 2.0f the same as 2.000000f?

Tags: c, ieee-754

Are these lines the same?

```
float a = 2.0f;
```

and

```
float a = 2.000000f;
```

Comment: If (2.0f == 2.000000f) then yes.

Comment: Well, what happens if you try that? Did you look at the output from the compiler?

Comment: please first try then ask

Comment: Simply trying things out rarely gives you definitive answers in C or C++.

Comment: It's not about whether `2.0f` is equal to `2.000000f`, but the general question whether such different representations have any influence on the executable or not. And the fact that on one machine using one compiler there's no difference doesn't mean that it will always be true on any platform/compiler/compilation flags.

Comment: The number one rule on SO is to answer the effing question _politely_. Wanna go re-read the [faq]? We are here to answer questions, not to demand proof or anything else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is. No matter what representation you use, when the code is compiled, the number will be converted to a unique binary representation. There's only one way of representing `2` in the [IEEE 754 binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) standard used in modern computers to represent `float` numbers.

Comment: However, there are other standards (I'm thinking of IBM 360) still in use where numbers have multiple representations... (not sure if 2 is one of them, though)

Comment: IEEE 754 allows multiple representations of the same value, notably in decimal floating point. E.g., 2 might be, in effect, 2e0 and 20e-1. However, the source texts “2.0f” and “2.000000f” are unlikely to result in different representations, and there is no difference in mathematical value.

Comment: But computer programs don't use the decimal representations at all, and in binary representations you can't do that, since there's an implicit `1.` prepended to the _fraction_ part of the number. I edited the answer to make it clearer that the binary32 representation is used.

Comment: Whether a program uses decimal floating point or not is dependent on the C (or other language) implementation. It is simply untrue to say computer programs do not use them. Why else would they exist?

Answer (score 9):

The only thing the C99 standard has to say on the matter is this (section 6.4.4.2):

> For decimal floating constants ... the result is either
>   the nearest representable value, or the larger or smaller representable value immediately
>   adjacent to the nearest representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner.

That bit about "implementation-defined" means that technically an implementation could choose to do something different in each case.  Although in practice, nothing weird is going to happen for a value like 2.

It's important to bear in mind that the C standards don't require IEEE-754.

Comment: Now, if IEEE-754 **is** used, the number `2` is exactly representable, and its neighbors ("the larger or smaller representable value immediately adjacent to the nearest representable value") are `1.99999988` and `2.00000024`. We can see that the neighbor to the right is twice as far away because we have one bit less for the fractional part when we move up to the next "duade" `2.0` to `4.0`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are the same.

Simple check:
http://codepad.org/FOQsufB4

```
int main() {
printf("%d",2.0f == 2.000000f);
}
```

^ Will output 1 (true)

Comment: Well, proving by an exemplary compiler is not a proof. (Your answer is of course correct, but the check isn't a proof.)

Comment: You're correct, I should have used different wording.  It seemed sufficient in this case, though.  The IEEE standard could be referenced for a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Sure it is the same extra zeros on the right are ignored just likes zeros on the left

Comment: Actually the zeros on the left do make a difference.

Comment: 00002.0 is similar to 02.0 no difference unless in printf or something

Comment: @Shehabox, What David meant (or so I thought) was that 010 is different from 10. The former is 8 in decimal and the latter is 10.